# Does not exist in the current context error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7

When i try to bind my Image in XAML to bitmapImage object in the code behind it gives me 
'Does not exist in the current context' error.

Code

```
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
PhotoSource.Source = bitmapImage;
ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> Photos = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();
PhotoList.ItemsSource = Photos;
```

XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,5,12,-10">
        <ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="436" Visibility="Collapsed" IsIndeterminate="True"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="PhotoList" 
                 toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"
                 SelectionChanged="PhotoList_SelectionChange"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="500" Margin="0,40,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="450">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                    />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="5">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            **<Image delay:LowProfileImageLoader.UriSource="{Binding PhotoSource}" Width="99" Height="80"/>**
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: You need to create such a property.

Comment: Error is self explanatory - `PhotoSource` doesn't exist.

Comment: ya, but it does : 
<Image delay:LowProfileImageLoader.UriSource="{Binding PhotoSource}" Width="99" Height="80"/>

Comment: @LivingThing: That code binds to a property that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

- Create some class which you want to bind to your. For example:

  ```
  private class Photo {
      public string PhotoSource {get; set;}
  }
  ```
- Create a collection which you want to bind. For example, `List<Photo> Photos = new List<Photo>();`
- Add some data to your list. For example, `Photos.Add(new Photo { PhotoSource = yourBitmap });`
- Bind it to your list. `PhotoList.ItemsSource = Photos;`

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure `PhotoSource` is a **public** property, since WPF doesn't recognize anything else.

Second, make sure you set your DataContext property properly. If the property is a part of the window's code behind, you can set the `DataContext` to the window, by setting the line:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}"
```

in the window declaration in the xaml, so it would look something like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}">
  <!-- Your Code here -->
</window>
```